# Validation failing while submitting the form via Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

I have created a form with remote=>true option. Usually i use client side validation gem for handling errors. When i submit the form normally that is without ajax client-side validation is working fine. When i submit the form with remote=>true(Ajax) validation is not working. When i give correct input my ajax is working fine. But when i give failing validation inputs it is not displaying any errors.

My create action is

```
def create
@post = @topic.posts.new(post_params)
@post.user=current_user
respond_to do |format|
  if @post.save
    flash[:notice] = "Post sent Successfully"
    format.html {redirect_to topic_post_path(id: @post.id)}
    format.js
else
    format.html {render :new}
    format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    format.js   { render layout: false, content_type: 'text/javascript' }
  end
end
end
```

create.js.erb is

```
$('#new_hide').fadeOut(1000)
$('#posts').empty();
$('.sort_paginate_ajax').append('<%= j render @post 
%>').ajaxSuccess(alert('you have created a post'))
```

I have ajax call for creating a new post in index as

```
<%= link_to "Add Post",new_topic_post_path,remote: true,id: "post"%>
<div class="row sort_paginate_ajax">
<%= render @posts %>
</div>
```

My new.js is

```
$('#post').hide().after('<%= j render :partial => "formm", :locals => { :button_label => "Create Post", :topic => @topic ,:post => @post} %>')
$('#new_form').enableClientSideValidations();
```

My form partial is

```
<div id="form-modal">
<%= form_for [topic,post], validate: true,:html=> {multipart: true}, 
remote: true do |f| %>
<p>
<%= f.label :title %><br>
<%= f.text_field :title , validate: { presence: true } %></p>
<%= f.label :description %><br>
<%= f.text_area :description ,validate: true ,required: true%>
</p>
 <p>
<%= f.submit button_label, class: "btn btn-success",id: "submit" %>
 </p>
<% end %>
 </div>
```

I'm using rails 5.1.6 and ruby 2.5.1p57